# Benchmarking Javascript, PHP and Dart

Tags: javascript, php, dart, benchmarking

I an running some experiments to research the feasibility of alternative server-side languages.  More for academic than for practical purposes.

The three I selected were Javascript (on Node), PHP and Dart.

I have tried to create a fair test using iterations.  These tests are as follows:

Javascript:

```
run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();

function run() {
    var sample = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
        sample = 'sample-'+i;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();

function run()
{
    $sample = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 20000000; $i++) {
        $sample = 'sample-'.$i;
    }
}
```

Dart:

```
main() {
    run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();
}

run()
{
    String sample = '';

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
        sample = 'sample-'+i.toString();
    }
}
```

Before I started the tests, I had expected the order of speed from fastest to slowest to be:
Dart > Javascript > PHP

However the true results I had were surprising to me:

```
> time node j.js
real    0m19.014s
user    0m19.093s
sys     0m0.068s

> time php p.php
real    0m24.543s
user    0m24.524s
sys     0m0.008s

> time dart d.dart
real    0m27.697s
user    0m27.788s
sys     0m0.149s
```

I would like to know if these results reflect the true performance difference between these runtimes, or if the test itself is incomplete or unfair?

UPDATE:

In response to the comments, I will clarify a few things.

- I am aware that a true application will not look like this, and that the real bottlenecks will come from overuse of resources/connections.  In those situations I will always choose the language I *like* the most.
- I included PHP in the test because it is the language I actively use.  I am familiar with JS, but I am uncomfortable using it for larger applications.  My main interest was a performance comparison between Dart and JS using the V8 engine, both invented by Google who showed that DartVM was faster.
- This specific test was to determine the performance of a simple high intensity repetition (I.E, a large loop, and a concatenation).  I will need to run a similar test for high intensity IO.

I don't think I properly asked the question, what I hoped to learn from posting was why in this relatively simple example, Dart is slower at iterations than the V8 Engine.

Comment: The issue with your tests is that they don't really represent the performance you'll get in an actual application. Each of the languages are faster in different circumstances. Personally I'd go with the language that you're most interested in learning -- all of these languages will be fast enough for a basic website.

Comment: if I were you I would use a `Stopwatch` within the program to time the execution

Comment: Did you ensure to run dart in non-checked mode? Otherwise this simple loop is not much of a benchmark. What really matters is the speed of the classes and in core and other frameworks. For example list insert/update/delete. What does the speed of an loop matter when your web server waits for a respone from the Database most of the time. Then it becomes much more important how comfortable concurrent programming is with the choosen language/framework. I don't know where you come from but nowadays the most important aspect is how productive you are with a language because dev time is expensive.

Comment: are your tests complete and representative? No, not even close... just rune `time node j.js` ten times. I'm prepared to bet that you're not going to see the same times show up every time again. Nor is what you're doing even remotely representative for what JS, PHP or dart are used for. On JS in particular, I'd like to point out that you're not benchmarking the language, but rather the V8 JS engine (which JIT compiles the JS code, and performs a ton of optimization trickery)

Comment: JS uses JIT, if you have some form of JIT for PHP like HHVM you would get the same or better performance out of PHP.

So you either get more information of what you are running behind those languages or risk not having a fair comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have clarified a few things so hopefully the question will be easier to answer.

Comment: When you launch a Dart app from DartEditor it runs in checked mode by default. This is a development-only mode which is notable slower than unchecked (production mode). If you run Dart from command line unchecked mode is default.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I ran all three in the command line, several times in different orders, on a 64bit Xubuntu.  The results varied slightly but negligible.

Comment: How do you measure time? Dart is not too fast on startup (as far as I know). It allows to create a snapshot of an initialized VM to improve startup time. If you measure within the benchmark app itself this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Time was measured with the Unix command `time`, originally I used a single call the `run` function, but the different in time between PHP and Dart were almost exactly the same, so I expanded the number of calls to dilute any initial overheads.

Comment: You are basically measuring two things: int.toString and String.+. That by itself is definitely not representative of performance of the languages in general. Different languages optimize different things. Fx V8 might create a "Cons" string in String.+, which is basically a pair of pointers to the two halves, and then flatten the string only when it's needed, where Dart will flatten the string every time. If you don't use the string for anything, V8's optimization will win every time. Also, you never read the "sample" variable, so a good optimizer could remove your entire program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benchmarks usually suck, but they still provide some value at least if they are well crafted.

The Dart team provides a few benchmarks with results at the dartlang.org site, see https://www.dartlang.org/performance/

Comment: I am going to have to wrap this up and accept the benchmarks provided by google are accurate in a practical environment.  This has been enlightening, but to be honest I now have more questions than before and I don't want to annoy anyone here :P

Answer (score 5):

It's not representative of anything, except the performance of int.toString and String.+ when used outside of any context.

For example, try changing the Dart version to:

```dart
main() {
  run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();run();
}

run() {
  String sample = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
    sample = 'sample-$i';
  }
}
```

If I do that, I get performance on the same level as JavaScript.

A good dead-code eliminator could remove your entire function: Since you never read 'sample', assignments to it can be eliminated. If int.toString and String.+ are recognized as not having side effects (which is possible), then that expression can also be removed. Then you have just a simple integer-indexed loop from 0 to 20000000, which is known to terminate with no side effects, so that too can be removed.

When you make benchmarks, always make sure that you have a final result that depend in some way on all the computations that you want to measure, or some day an optimizing compiler will just remove it all and complete in zero seconds.

Comment: For me that alteration brought Dart down to 23 seconds, making it faster than the PHP version.. I have to admit I've approached this research in all the wrong ways.. +1

Comment: I also just wrote the same test in C which scored 1 second less than javascript so now im totally lost..

Answer (score 0):

String-concatenation can be implemented in different ways. For example, V8 uses "cons-strings" to concatenate two strings. That is, they actually don't concatenate the strings, but build a new representation that says: "this string is the concatenation of these two other strings". This is particularly effective when building up bigger strings in smaller steps. However, it can also use more memory.

See this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20730), where we had to change the implementation of dart2js' string buffer, because it was exploding in memory. The reason was the cons-strings that were using up all the memory.

Your benchmark is hence not representative of the actual speed of the three vms.